# Behavior of higher() method of TreeSet collection when it is in descending mode?

Tags: java, collections

Could any body describe this behavior of higher() method of TreeSet collection when it is  sorted in descending order:

**Code:**

```
NavigableSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();

set.add(10);
set.add(22);
set.add(34);
set.add(40);
set.add(45);
set.add(56);
set.add(77);
set.add(79);
set.add(84);
set.add(99);

set = set.descendingSet();

System.out.printf("%n Higher than 40 : %s", set.higher(40));
```

**It returns following result viz.**

```
Higher than 40 : 34
```

Now, although collection is sorted in descending order still `higher(40)` method should return a value higher than 40 (which is of course 45) or not?

Answer (score 5):

- [`set.higher(T)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#higher%28E%29): function returns the least element in this set strictly greater than the given element, or `null` if there is no such element.
- [`set.descendingSet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#descendingSet%28%29): returns a reverse order `view` of the elements contained in this `set`.

**What really happens ?**

`TreeSet` inherently uses `TreeMap` to implements its functionality. The call to `descendingSet()` eventually call the `descendingMap()` function on the `TreeMap` instance, as is evident from the following source code:

```
public NavigableSet<E> descendingSet() {
        return new TreeSet<>(m.descendingMap());
    }
```

Every `TreeMap` generally maintains two view:

- *normal sorted view*: uses general comparator to order its element
- *descendant Map view*: uses comparator which imposes reverse ordering of the ascend-ordering comparator. It uses `Collections.reverseOrder(m.comparator())` to return this descend-ordering comparator.

I am calling these `view` because `TreeMap` doesn't actually create another descendent Map with it's *entries(key, value)*, rather it maintains two comparator, imposing opposite ordering to each other. The descendant view gets created first time when `descendantMap()` is called. Any subsequent call to this function will return the same descendent Map view.

**Note:**  `set.descendingSet().descendingSet()` returns a view of `set` essentially equivalent to `set`. Because the resulted comparator from first call got reversed *again* by the second call of `descendingSet()`(which is actually executing `map.descendingMap()` inside).

**Continuing with your Example:**

```
System.out.printf("%n Higher than 40 : %s", set.higher(40)); // prints 45
set = set.descendingSet(); // create a reverse ordering 
                           //comparator as described above 
System.out.printf("%n Higher than 40 : %s", set.higher(40)); // prints 34
set = set.descendingSet(); // again trying to get descending set!
System.out.printf("%n Higher than 40 : %s", set.higher(40))  // prints 45
```

Comment: Well, of course answer is quite informative and thanks for that.